# How to pass Jenkins Pipeline Parameters via GitHub?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-github-plugin

I have Jenkins Jobs with a lot of parameters that varies depending on environment**(DEV, PRE-PROD, PROD)**. Can I pass parameters by storing them in GitHub?

For example, if I select **DEV** and start build, pipeline should go and fetch parameters from GitHub and do its Job. Is this possible? If yes how? Please help.

Comment: Unclear what exactly you're trying to do. Why not define one parameter named "Environment" and code the relevant values in Jenkinsfile?

Comment: You can pass parameter and based on parameter, checkout required file(s) from Github, which has other parameters.